# Am I following flux if I use browserHistory.push() inside of a nested react component?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

According to the react-router documentation doing a browserHistory.push() inside of a nested react component is the accepted way to change the current route in a react-router app:
https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/latest/upgrade-guides/v2.0.0.md#navigating-inside-deeply-nested-components

If a route change is considered a change of state, which I'm not sure whether it is or not hence why I'm asking, would't this be anti-flux?

If a route change isn't considered a change of state, then I guess the documented way is correct.

Can someone weigh in on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"State" is kind of an arbitrary term. Ultimately, flux gives you the flexibility to decide where you wan to store state when there are multiple possible places to track it. Some data is managed within its own component, and other data is managed in a flux type store to share with other components. And there are a lot of things that are managed by the browser that you wouldn't keep in your application state--for example, currently selected input box. You could keep them in your flux state if you wanted, or you could keep them in your component state. Or you could let the browser handle that and not worry about it. It all depends on how you want to make these data available across your application.

The URL location is an example of a state which can be maintained by the browser outside of the flux or component state trees. You can, however include it in your store and bind to it if you feel you need it in your application in a way that would be useful. [`react-router-redux`](https://github.com/rackt/react-router-redux) specifically is an example of an implementation that brings the location bar in to the flux state for `redux` applications.

At the end of the day, however, its up to you to determine if having that information available in your flux state is useful or not. Pedantically speaking, yes, you should have all of your data in flux to have the most pure flux implementation, but that's not really what you should be optimizing for.

The documentation for `react-router` is perfectly correct to use in a flux application, but if you're using something like `redux`, it's at least nice to have a real `react-router` integration so that it doesn't become something of an exception on how your application deals with state.

Comment: Hey Nathan, thanks! We're not using Redux so that simplifies things...I guess. We were just hashing through this at the office and I think if you look at browserHistory.push() as an action being dispatched and picked up by the react-router store, we are still following flux.

Comment: I think thats a fair way to look at it. If you wanted to bring it into your own flux implementation, you could use `react-router-redux` as a model for how that would work on a high level. Its concept is pretty simple